# Any way to return a ResultSet in Java?

Tags: java, web-services

I found out that Java doesn't let ResultSet to be return as a data type. And would like to ask whether is there any better solution to return results after executing query?

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopping mall?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "" );

        java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement() ;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE SHOPNAME LIKE \'%" + shopName + "%\' ORDER BY shopname ASC";           // Select and sort using user input
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query) ;

        // How to return the result after executing the query?
    }
    catch ( SQLException err ) {
        return null;
    }
```

Don't mind the `return null;` part. Was testing something. Basically this is my current code for now. How can I return the result after executing query?

Comment: What are you talking about? It's perfectly acceptable to return a `ResultSet`. Is the actual problem that you're declaring your `rs` variable inside your `try` block and then trying to return it later on?

Comment: I googled around some saying it is the return-ing of ResultSet that cause error. `Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet web service endpoint '' failure`. Now I'm confused.

Comment: If so, how do I return a ResultSet? Can you please guide me?

Comment: If the compiler is not allowing you to do this is protecting you against some poor programming practices.  Returning a result set is akin to shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @PeteBelford - Why so?

Comment: @PeteBelford How come? Can you please explain why does it happens?

Comment: @user3054491 If you are returning the `ResultSet` as `web service` method `Response`

Comment: @Deepak Meaning using the method `Response`?

Comment: @user3054491 Are you using web services if yes then Please update the question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide better context for the error. Is this, for example, a JAX-WS web service endpoint? Anyway, as stated in the trace, your error is a web service error--not a JDBC error. This error can happen for many reasons--usually related to something wrong with the way you are defining the API to your service.

You are certainly allowed to return a `ResultSet` from a method even if that is a very bad idea, especially from a web service endpoint. A `ResultSet` can't be serialized into a SOAP message. More generally, to return a `ResultSet` betrays implementation details to the callers of the method. Why should they know you are using JDBC? Or even that you are talking to a relational (or any) database at all?

The better approach is to populate a model object relevant to your domain with the data in the `ResultSet`, and that object will be serialized to SOAP via JAXB or whatever you use. Or maybe you just return some text from the database, in which case JAX-WS knows what to do.

Also, make sure you do something with `SQLException` so you can trace the cause of your actual JDBC errors.

Comment: Vidya i think he is returning the `ResultSet` as web service method `Response` `java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet web service endpoint  failure`

Comment: That's what I am afraid of. I can't say for sure that would cause the error because I have never seen anyone attempt to return a `ResultSet` from a method. But I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea of returning a `ResultSet` if that so, what method is best practice to return query result?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do, but the basic idea is to populate a model with the data and return the model to the client (and the model will be serialized into SOAP via JAXB or similar). Or maybe you just want to return text via a `String` you fetched from the database. The point is you want to return an object pertinent to your use case--not a data repository.

Comment: I see. Really thank you for the information. I'll look around see what I can do.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

You write a method to retrieve info from a database, where should the data be processed and put into a model class?  If you want code that is loosely coupled, then 98% of the time you would process the result set within the same method.

What happens if the query needs to change?  You want the changes to be localized into a small of a subset of code as possible.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explaination. I'll need to Google more about this. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Spring-JDBC JdbcTemplate. This method

```
List<Map<String, Object>> queryForList(String sql)
```

returns a List that contains a Map per row. You can use it or make something similar